# Can you have a difference as a dependent variable?

Tags: regression

I wondering if it makes sense to have a dependent variable be a difference of the current period compared to the previous period in a cross sectional analysis.

Say i only have data for 2 years for many individuals and i want to compare how the independent variables in the current year $x_1, x_2$ affect the change in $y$ since the previous year for each individual.

in this case i suppose the model would be:

$$\varDelta y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 $$

Does this make sense ? Something about this feels wrong but im not really sure what the reason is behind not being able to do this.

Comment: It's not an uncommon practice: https://statisticalhorizons.com/wp-content/uploads/Allison.SM90.pdf, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233096995_Examining_change_using_regression_analysis_Three_approaches_compared, https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fams.2018.00064/full

Comment: Thanks for the sources. All 3 of these research papers do discuss the issues with using this type of approach however its a good starting point on how to correct for such things when building the model. Thanks again!

Comment: Here is another quite famous example from economics: https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w4058/w4058.pdf

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated: come with a question, leave with your lit review :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is entirely possible, although more interesting would likely be the slightly different Log-Linear regression, where a change of 1 unit in X is associated to a 100*B1 % increase in Y.